# Why is the following assignment of an int * arr[] allowed in C?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I tried to type this in both C and C++:

```
int* arr[3]={1,2,3};
```

C doesn't report an error and prints 1 when I dereference array, and C++ reports an error for the wrong type assigned to int * [], which is what I expected. Why is C allowing this?

Comment: Are you sure about the `int*`? Accessing a literal memory  address at 1, 2 or 3 is probably not what you intend to do. Also c++ probably requires a `const` there.

Comment: Because you didn't enable `-Werror` and didn't look at the warnings?

Comment: Detail `int* arr[3]={1,2,3};` is _initialization_, not _assignment_.

Comment: @kastle "C++ reports an error" --> It is best to post the exact error message.   What was it on your machine?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, I'm sure I was initializing an int* []. I didn't intend to do this but just curious why will this initialization be compiled in C.

Comment: @cpplearner There's a warning that says "warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast", I'm wondering why is this compiled. I probably didn't enable the -Werror.

Comment: @chux Right. Initialization instead of assignment. The error on c++ says " error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'int' to 'int *' ". I think this should also be expected in C, but it still compiles for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> C doesn't report an error and prints 1 when I dereference array, and C++ reports an error for the wrong type assigned to int * [], which is what I expected. Why is C allowing this?

**C** is not allowing it.  *Your C compiler* is accepting it without comment, despite the fact that it does not conform to the C language.  Chances are good that you could persuade your C compiler to warn about that initialization by turning on appropriate warning options.

Your initializer provides values of type `int` to initialize array elements of type `int *`.  C does allow integers to be converted to pointers and pointers to be converted to integers, but these are not among the conversions that the standard says are performed automatically during object initialization.  Explicit casts are required for conformance with the standard (C99 or later):

```
int *arr[3] = { (int *) 1, (int *) 2, (int *) 3 };
```

C's history predates its standardization by a long way, however, and it was common for early C compilers to accept such implicit conversions.  There is still a fair amount of code in the wild that relies on them.  Some modern C compilers therefore accept such conversions without a cast as an extension.  Some of those even do so silently by default, even though the standard in fact requires a diagnostic to be emitted.

There is a host of other issues surrounding the meaning of the pointers obtained from such conversions and the effect of dereferencing one.  C itself does not specify.

Comment: You seem to have confused yourself somewhere. C99/6.7.8p16 says "the initializer for an object that has aggregate ... type shall be a brace- enclosed list of initializers ...", and `int *` is a scalar so p10 says "The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, ... The initial value of the object is that of the expression (after conversion);" in C11 it's 6.7.9. C89 has different words emphasising the conversion, but there appears to be no standard implicit integer-to-pointer conversion in C89. Thus, it appears to me as though your mind has done a fliparoo or missed a conversion.

Comment: I do not follow, @autistic.  Each element of the array being initialized is an `int *`, and the initializer values the OP's code presents are integers.  The "after conversion" in your quotation from the language spec refers to the immediately following clause: "the same type constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply," and we seem to agree that these constraints and conversions do not provide for pointer-to-integer conversion.  Explicit casts are therefore required, just as for simple assignment.  What part, exactly, do you claim is wrong?

Comment: Have *you* perhaps been confused, @autistic?  The object being initialized is an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array.

Comment: John, an array is an aggregate type, so I cited the section that covers that. Each pointer in the array is a scalar type, so I cited the section that covers that. I don't agree that "[these constraints and conversions](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p5) do not provide for pointer-to-integer [sic] conversion", for as you can see I have linked to the section permitting such conversions (except C89, which as I previously mentioned hasn't got this). I never claimed the object was "a pointer to an array", so I'm not sure why you raised that non-sequitur.

Comment: My apologies, @autistic, I was loose with my language.  Certainly it is permitted in a general sense to convert integers to pointers and *vise versa*, but C does not define any circumstances where that is done **automatically**.  The conversions that are performed automatically on the elements of an initializer are the same ones that are performed automatically for simple assignment, and those do not include integer-to-pointer conversions.  In a strictly conforming program, integer-to-poiunter conversions are performed only via typecast.

Answer (score 3):

Your declaration is for an array of `int *` initialised to `{1,2,3}`, which is somewhat dubious in both programming languages. In C, what happens is a conversion from each `int` value to an `int *` value and there's quite a bit of implementation-defined and undefined behaviour around [that conversion](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p5). It's very possible that the undefined behaviour for your system might correlate with your expectations, and unclear what your expectations were, so I can't suggest better alternatives. To answer the question directly

> Why is C allowing this?

Standard C doesn't *allow* or *forbid* this because standard C doesn't *define* this. Sometimes we leave things *undefined* to leave the freedom to *allow* (per-implementation) them at a later date...

I see some alignment requirement violations most certainly causing undefined behaviour on typical x86/64 configurations, most likely corresponding to a warning or error message (depending on configuration) at compile time. On some DSPs this might be a valid construct so you wouldn't see a warning or error message, however, be aware, it's *not* portable C code.

It's kind of like how our signed integer overflows commonly wrap in `int fubar = INT_MAX; fubar++;`, and how we commonly type-pin using `union`. The behaviour is undefined there, too, but we have some common norm which explains what we're going to commonly see; rather than expecting a *crash* we expect some other behaviour. We can change the *undefined behaviour* to suite our requirements depending on whether we're debugging or releasing. For example, we can possibly get this construct to *function* (whatever that means) on an x86/64 configuration by mapping our programs address space to start at `(void *) 1` using some kernel wizardry or something, but then when we enable alignment checking for x86/64 we'll see crashes again. Similarly we can enable trap on integer overflow and uninitialised variables.

In any case, this is all squarely non-portable and non-C. If you have a manual explicitly *allowing* it for your given architecture or implementation or build configuration, then it's *allowed* by that manual (as opposed to the C standard). Otherwise, this code has some red flags to address, in the form of those warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, did you really mean:

```
int arr[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

C is less strict with its casting rules, so C is OK with you making an array of pointers-to-int, with the pointers pointing to memory-addresses: 0x00000001, 0x00000002 and 0x00000003.

With warnings turned on, GCC (7.3.0 in C mode) does say:

```
pointers.c:2:17: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
int *arr[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
                ^
```

However, C++ is not OK with it:

```
pointers.cpp:2:25: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ 
 int *arr[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
                         ^
pointers.cpp:2:25: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ 
pointers.cpp:2:25: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’
```

But, if you cast it, C++ is OK with it too:

```
int *arr[3] = { (int*)1, (int*)2, (int*)3 };
```

Which compiles without even a warning.

Comment: Although C may be less strict about conversions, it no more permits implicit conversion from integer to pointer than does C++.